# RPX token URL problem

Tags: session, cakephp, ssl, openid, rpxnow

I am using RPX in my CakePHP project. I have set the toke url like this: http://www.mysite.com/users/login

Here is my login action code.

```
function login() {
    $this->Ssl->force();        
    $this->layout = 'colorbox';
    $this->pageTitle = "User Login";
}
```

I have used SSL with the login form. Look above code( `$this->Ssl->force();` ). Login using RPX works fine without SSL. I commented `$this->Ssl->force();` line, and got RPX working properly. But when I uncommented that Ssl code, it doesn't work properly.

when ssl code was uncommented there, I did this.
 1. Selected google to login from RPX badge (in my login form)
 2. Entered my google id and password to login and it worked.
 3. But I was redirected back to the login form without any session.

Can any one help me please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current code redirects the login page from http:// to https:// and therefore it loses the session and other token data. So need to use either http or https before and after redirecting from RPX to my site.
Thanks.